# Pass image file from angular to nodejs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

```
var data = {artName: name, artFileLocations: this.selectedArtFiles};
this.adminService.adminAddPainting(data).subscribe();
```

I am trying to send the data from angular to node.js server. artName has simple string and artFileLocations has array of image File

[image]

This information is available in frontend. When passed to backend I get empty array like [{},{}]

req.files also gives undefined

**EDIT:**

Code on server side

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Paintings = require('../../models/Paintings');
var router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Reaching addPainting')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.files))
    // (new Paintings({ 'artName': req.body.artName, 'artFileLocations': req.body.artFileLocations}))
    // .save()
    // .then((artInfo) => res.send(artInfo))
    // .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your backend code or snippet of it ?

Comment: Added thee code

Comment: can you print entire req ? See what is the output.

Comment: req gives a long output, is there any specific part you want to see?